# Como criar um array com strings na quantidade de valores contidos em outro array

Tags: php, php-7

Eu estou tentando criar um novo array com as string sendo exibidas na mesma quantidade de valores contidos em outro array. Isso deve ser fácil, porém não estou conseguindo entender a lógica para criar um novo array e exibir essas strings de acordo com a quantidade dos valores de outro array.
Mais ou menos assim.

```
$A = array('A','B','C','D');<br>
$B = array(4, 2, 1, 1);<br><br>
```

Resultado que procuro é deveria ser assim.

```
['A','B','C','D']
['A','B']
['A']
['A']
```

Ou seja, a primeira letra deve aparecer na quantidade de vezes do primeiro valor da `$B`, a segunda letra conforme o segundo valor do `$B` e assim sucessivamente. Já tentei usar o `array_splice` dentro de um `foreach` e não deu certo.
Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?
Desde já agradeço a todos.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta como foi sua tentativa em resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é o exatamente o que perguntou, pois não entendi o que queria, mas neste caso o resultado na tela é este

['A','B','C','D']['A','B']['A']['A']

```
<?php

$A = array('A','B','C','D');
$B = array(4, 2, 1, 1);

$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($B as &$value) {
    echo '[';
    for( $i =0; $i < $value; $i++) {
       if( $i+1 < $value)
        echo "'$A[$i]'," ;
       else
        echo "'$A[$i]'" ;
    }
    echo ']';
}
```

Comment: Obrigado companheiro, mas ainda não é isso que eu preciso. Mas com esse exemplo já me ajudou muito a buscar uma direção.